Let $(M,g)$ be a (compact) Riemannian manifold with isometry group $G$. Who is the isometry group of the volume form $\rho d\operatorname{vol}$?
Let $(M,g)$ be a (compact) Riemannian manifold with isometry group $G$. That is, if $F\in G$, $F^*d\operatorname{vol}=d\operatorname{vol}$.
Who is the isometry group of the volume form $\rho d\operatorname{vol}$? That is, who are the smooth maps $F:M\to M$ such that $F^*(\rho d\operatorname{vol})=\rho d\operatorname{vol}$ for $\rho \in C^\infty(M)$?
For example, the isometry group of the circle is formed by the rotations $O(2,\mathbb{R})$. Who is the isometry group of $\rho d\operatorname{vol}_{S^1}$?

In general there will be many such maps. If $\rho>0$, the map $\iota_X\rho dvol$ yields an isomorphism $\mathfrak{X}\to\Omega^{n-1}(M)$. Since $\mathcal{L}_X \rho dvol=d\iota_X \rho dvol$ any vector field $X$ will generate a volume preserving map for $\rho dvol$ if and only if the form $\iota_X\rho dvol$ is closed. The space of closed forms is in general an infinite dimensional space.

@J.V.Gaiter but can't I write this new "isometry group" (the isotropy group of $\rho dvol$ by pullbacks) in terms of the initial isometry group?

@J.V.Gaiter it suffices to me to understand in the case when $M=S^1$, as in my example.

When $\rho$ is invariant, $G$ lives as a sub group, but you will not find any other restrictions. The case of $S^1$ is somewhat misleading, as the only divergence-free vector fields are the constant ones. Try thinking about the local description on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and about how many linearly independent divergence free vectorfields there are there.
